# Provisioning Issue using CrmDeploymentService

Tags: deployment, dynamics-crm-4

i've been working on Provision of an organization for quite a few days , and had faced  few issues which i was successful in resolving them.Let me explain abt the issues i faced, the MSCrmServices is a process that is running under the Network Service.
When I call the 'Execute' method on the service from a console application
all actions preformed run under the context of the 'Network Service' account.
The Network Service account has not enough rights to create an organization
so many problems occur during the action.

- Registry access not allowed.
- Not the correct SQL Server rights
- Not enough AD rights.
- ...

Impersonation doesn't work, the service uses the process account to perform
the actions.  The only thing that works is to run the CRMAppPool identity as
an administrator which has the deployment administrator rights (added through
the Deployment manager tool).
 But this issues in CRM deployment doesnt seem to faceoff from me :(. now that i have a new issue after changing the Pool identity to the system administrator, the deployment service gives an error saying Unauthorized!!!! and further when i check the log it says..

> Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   |Thread:    1 |Category: Exception |User:
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |
>   CrmException..ctor
>
> at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32
>   errorCode, Boolean isFlowControlException, Boolean enableTrace)
>
> at CrmException..ctor(String message, Int32 errorCode)
>
> at CrmObjectNotFoundException..ctor(BusinessEntityMoniker moniker)
>
> at
>   BusinessProcessObject.DoRetrievePublishableSingle(BusinessEntityMoniker
>   moniker, EntityExpression entityExpression, Boolean
>   includeUnpublished, ExecutionContext context)
>
> at BusinessProcessObject.RetrieveUnpublished(BusinessEntityMoniker
>   moniker, EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)
>
> at OrganizationUIService.RetrieveUnpublished(BusinessEntityMoniker
>   moniker, EntityExpression entityExpression, ExecutionContext context)
>
> at OrganizationUIService.RetrieveOldFormXml(BusinessEntityMoniker
>   moniker, ExecutionContext context)
>
> at OrganizationUIService.ExtractAndSaveFormLabels(IBusinessEntity
>   entity, ExecutionContext context)
>
> at OrganizationUIService.Create(IBusinessEntity entity,
>   ExecutionContext context)
>
> at ImportFormXmlHandler.createOrgUI(OrganizationUIService
>   orgUIService, XmlNode formNode)
>
> at ImportFormXmlHandler.ImportItem()
>
> at ImportHandler.Import()
>
> at ImportHandler.Import()
>
> at RootImportHandler.RunImport()
>
> at ImportXml.RunImport()
>
> at NewOrgUtility.OrganizationImportDefaultData(Guid organizationId,
>   Version existingDatabaseVersion, String importFile)
>
> at NewOrgUtility.OrganizationImportDefaultData(Guid organizationId,
>   String importFile)
>
> at NewOrgUtility.ConfigureOrganization(String organizationId, String
>   organizationName, String userAccountName, String userFirstName, String
>   userLastName, String userEmail, String languageCode, String
>   privilegedUserGroup, String sqlAccessGroup, String userGroup, String
>   reportingGroup, String privilegedReportingGroup, Boolean
>   grantNetworkServiceAccess, Boolean autoGroupManagement, String
>   importFileLocation, Boolean sqmOption)
>
> at CreateOrganizationInstaller.Create(Guid organizationId, String
>   organizationUniqueName, String organizationFriendlyName, String
>   baseCurrencyCode, String baseCurrencyName, String baseCurrencySymbol,
>   String initialUserDomainName, String initialUserFirstName, String
>   initialUserLastName, String sqlServerName, Uri reportServerUrl, String
>   privilegedUserGroupName, String sqlAccessGroupName, String
>   userGroupName, String reportingGroupName, String
>   privilegedReportingGroupName, String applicationPath, String
>   languageId, Boolean sqmOption, String organizationCollation,
>   MultipleTenancy multipleTenancy)
>
> at CreateOrganizationInstaller.Create(ICreateOrganizationInfo
>   organizationInfo)
>
> at OrganizationService.Create(DeploymentEntity entity)
>
> at CreateRequest.Process()
>
> at CrmDeploymentService.Execute(DeploymentServiceRequest request)
>
> at RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
>
> at RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
>
> at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks)
>
> at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>
> at LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
>
> at WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
>
> at WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
>
> at SyncSessionlessHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>
> at
>   CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>
> at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)
>
> at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
>
> at
>   HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
>
> at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>
> at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>
> at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)

Any idea on this.?

Have anyone of you come across such an issue. I've been trying to resolve this issue but hard luck.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  Actually you're not alone.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31450420/crmdeploymentservice-crm.aspx

Hope that helps.